# How to add new block to view.php (Catalog/Product/view.php)

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, view

I am trying to add button to view.php but i can't do this. I need any step by step tutorial how to do this, can anyone help me?

---

Thanks for reply i did something like this:
i create my own template here:

> app/design/frontend/module/MyTheme/template/catalog/product

I have here view.phtml and i have

> app/design/frontend/module/MyTheme/template/catalog/product/view

and in this folder i have sub.phtml i want to see sub.phtml in view.phtml but while i do something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sub') ?>
```

It'snt visible on Product View so do you maybe know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
So i did create file in path:

> app/design/frontend/module(namespace)/MyTheme/layout/sub.xml
>   Inside this file i wrote something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
         <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
    </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

And now it should works?

Answer (score 0):

`view.php` is a  block class. My suggestion **donot do anything at this block**.

If want to change **anything then please go at this block class** template `phtml files`.

basically this `view.php` 's template is `view.phtml` which is located at `app/design/frontend/[Yourpackage/[YourTheme]/template/catalog/product/`.

You should **do required changes at this phtml file**

**edit:**

As you want to call `catalog/product/view/delivery.phtml` in `catalog/product/view.phtml` then you should  to call your phtml file under block `name="product.info"`  . at layout xml file catalog.xml

```
 <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

........

**Or ,you can call this phtml via direct call of sub.phtml at view.phtml**

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/sub.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: what if it doesn't change for me?i mean view

Comment: so if i did create file - module/MyTheme/layout/sub.xml and i did add in tihs something like:

Comment: it still don't work for me in my own template folder i have changed this block in sub.xml and i refreshed page nothing  happend so i think it's not working

Comment: why only while i modify rdw view.php i see changed on homepage? so how can i overide rdw file?